# Cannot upload files exceeding 1MB in size - PHP webserver

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-security

I am currently having a bit of a nightmare with a webserver I have. I have trawled just about every Stack Overflow page I can find and still no success.

I have a webserver running locally which I would test these settings on first, and everything works but whenever I apply the same settings to my main server, no such luck.

I have gone right back to basics just by using a simple html page and php page to process the request and this still fails with anything over 1MB.

For reference, this is my html script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my test.php page to process the request:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 8000000) { //8mb
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

This is just the basic php image upload script from w3 Schools - that is what this problem has reduced me to!

What I have tried:

- Editing the php.ini file then restarting apache
- Changing the html form so that it includes enctype="multipart/form-data" within the form header
- Adding .htaccess to the root www/html folder where the files are
- changing the bit of the upload script which specifies the maximum allowed image size:

The error I am getting is:

```
Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/html/test.php on line 8
File is not an image.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.
```

Can anyone help me out? I have also tried to look into disabling mod_security but I couldn't even find that on my apache2 server.

Many thanks.

Comment: So is the error you get about `getimagesize()` on both local server and main? You get _that_ by uploading file larger than 1 MB?

Comment: Maybe you are exceeding your default time limit, because your files are over 1MB. Try setting time limit to unlimited with `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: No, I only have the error on the main server. Everything works great when I try it on my webserver running on my laptop, just when I push it to the main server.  Looking at set_time_limit(0) - I added that to the php script but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the upload limit by two ways as below

i)Change the value of the upload_max_filesize in php.ini

ii)Using ini_set("upload_max_filesize","30M");

Comment: Where might you set ini_set("upload_max_filesize","30M"); ?

Comment: Oh nevermind, added that into the php file too but to no avail - still searching for a solution.